# Migration to hibernate core 5.2.1 ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-4, hibernate-5.x

Using spring version:4.3.1,Spring data:1.10.2,hibernate core: 5.2.1.
using postgres Database pg connector version :9.4.1208.jre7
After upgrading from hibernate 5.1.0 to 5.2.1 when i am trying to create an entity getting below exception

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.cando.person.controller.UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$250a315a.createDefaultUser(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.prepareFlushMode(HibernateJpaDialect.java:187)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:173)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    ... 51 more
```

java config

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories( "com.cando.**.repository" )
@PropertySource( "classpath:spring.properties" )
public class SpringDataConfig
{
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    // Declare a datasource
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        try
        {
            boolean productionProfile = checkProfileIsActive( IConstants.PROFILE_PRODUCTION );
            String driverClassName = productionProfile ? env.getRequiredProperty( "production.app.jdbc.driverClassName" ) : env.getRequiredProperty( "dev.app.jdbc.driverClassName" );
            String url = productionProfile ? env.getRequiredProperty( "production.app.jdbc.url" ) : env.getRequiredProperty( "dev.app.jdbc.url" );
            String username = productionProfile ? env.getRequiredProperty( "production.app.jdbc.username" ) : env.getRequiredProperty( "dev.app.jdbc.username" );
            String password = productionProfile ? env.getRequiredProperty( "production.app.jdbc.password" ) : env.getRequiredProperty( "dev.app.jdbc.password" );

            System.out.println( driverClassName + " " + url + " " + username + " " + password );

            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName( driverClassName );
            dataSource.setUrl( url);
            dataSource.setUsername( username );
            dataSource.setPassword( password );
            return dataSource;
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }

    // Declare a JPA entityManagerFactory
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()
    {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource( dataSource() );
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan( "com.cando.**.model" );


        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put( "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect" );
        properties.put( "hibernate.show_sql", false );
        properties.put( "hibernate.format_sql", false );
        //properties.put( "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update" );
        properties.put( "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop" );


        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties( properties );

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl( Boolean.TRUE );
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql( Boolean.TRUE );

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter( vendorAdapter );

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    // Declare a transaction manager
    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager()
    {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory( entityManagerFactory().getObject() );
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private boolean checkProfileIsActive( String profileName )
    {
        for ( String profile : env.getActiveProfiles() )
        {
            if ( StringUtils.equals( profileName, profile ) )
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Github code: https://github.com/arun472/spring-data-jpa**

Comment: Please post your pom.xml to investigate further.

Comment: i have added github link where pom.xml is available

Answer (score 11):

This looks as a Jar conflict for Spring Framework 4.3.0.RELEASE version which you have chosen. Please downgrade it to hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar.

Comment: Yes, Method signature for FlushMode enum is different, Hence this issues. I have updated my answer to choose the appropriate version of hibernate-core-5.10.Final.jar

Answer (score 3):

I found that the class ConfigurationHelper which implements the method 
    `public static getFlushMode( Object value )`
 in hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.2.Final.jar in package org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util conflicts with the correct method signature which includes the default value that is implemented in hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar.
The wrong implementation was resolved. I removed the dependency hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.2.Final.jar from my gradle.build file which already includes the dependency hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar and that sorted out the method not found exception

Answer (score 2):

This looks odd as the method signature support for the Hibernate 5.2 API was added in Spring Framework 4.3.0.RELEASE where it specifically looks for `getHibernateFlushMode` first and is then followed up by `getFlushMode`.

I'd say chances are you likely have the new Hibernate libraries on your classpath but you may have an older version of Spring Framework in the classpath which isn't compatible.